# Can the python interpreter tell me where its header files are?

Tags: python, build, include, c-header

In debian/CentOS systems, python's excutable, header and library files are organized like:

```
/usr/(local/|)/bin/python
/usr/(local/|)/include/python-$version$/
/usr/(local/|)/libs
```

But on Windows, the folder structure is a bit different

```
C:\\Program\ Files\\Python$version$\\python.exe
C:\\Program\ Files\\Python$version$\\include\
C:\\Program\ Files\\Python$version$\\libs
```

the sys module can tell me where the executable is in `sys.executable` and the general folder where all python files are installed in `sys.base_prefix`, can it or some other module tell me where the header files are?

Answer (score 3):

This information is available in distutils.sysconfig and sysconfig, i.e.:

prior to python 3.2

```
from distutils import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_python_inc()
```

more recent pythons:

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_config_var("INCLUDEPY")
```